# Loading .ttf font in JavaFX is pixelated on windows

Tags: java, css, javafx, fonts

I'm trying to load a .ttf font in my JavaFx application. This is my project structure:

```
main
- java
- - Application.java
- resources
- - fonts
- - - static
- - - - Raleway-Thin.ttf
- - - - Ralewy-Regular.ttf
- - - - ...
- - - Raleway-VairableFont_wght.ttf
- - main.css
```

On linux, everything worked fine when loading the static fonts in `start(Stage stage)` like this:

```java
Font.loadFont(getClass.getResourceAsStream("fonts/static/Raleway-Thin.ttf"), 12);
... //Here I load all types I need
```

and referencing them in `main.css` just like this:

```css
.button {
    -fx-font-family: 'Raleway Thin', sans-serif;
}
```

On windows, the font looks bad:

[image: Windows Example]

It does load the font, it is indeed [Raleway](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway) Bold, but it looks very ugly.

I have tried the following and will gladly elaborate on everything in more detail if necessary:

- Load VariableFont_wgth with `Font.loadFonts(...)`.
  This would be the best way, but it only loads `Raleway Thin` when doing this. I guess I would need a `.ttc` file for doing this. Furthermore, it is still pixelated.
- I tried using the css tag `@font-face`. This didn't solve the pixelated text.
- I tried to change the second argument `size` of `Font.loadFont()`, I don't really understand the purpose of it, even after reading the documentations.

What might cause this and how can I solve it? I can't rely on the user having the font installed on the system.